# Transfer data from 1 scene to the 2 scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(I want to make a 2d game with unity)

I would like to pass the coin values from the first scene to the second one.

I would like to take the coins from the first scene and set them as start point for the second scene,

Can someone explain me how it works via serialize?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CoinFinal : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Für die Coinanzeige
    public float coins = 1;
    public Text CoinsAnzeige;
    public GameObject house;




    void Start()
    {
        CoinsAnzeige.text = coins.ToString();
        house.SetActive(false);
    }


    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("coinblock"))
            coins++;

   

    }

    void Update()
    {
        CoinsAnzeige.text = " " + coins.ToString();

        if (coins > 9)
        {
            house.SetActive(true);
        }
    }


}
```

Found a Way:

```
void Start()
{
    CoinTest = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("myScore");
}


void Update()
{
    CoinUebergabe.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("myScore").ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned already you could use static variables. Another way would be to save the information in the `PlayerPrefs` and load it from them again. A maybe less dirty way would be `DontDestroyOnLoad`. even though I mentiond this two ways I think a Class with static attributes would be the best.

Answer (score 2):

This concept could be easily handled typically as "GameManager". [Singleton](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton)

Here's the code I usually use:

Create empty gameobject in hierarchy window and attach this script:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public float coins;

private static GameManager _instance;
public static GameManager Instance
{
    get
    {
        return _instance;
    }
}

private void Awake()
{
    if (_instance != null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        _instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

now you can access to your public properties at any time for example:

```
GameManager.Instance.coins = 3;
```